# Escapse url GET parameters in URL with Java/ICEFaces

Tags: java, jsf, icefaces

I have a JAVA with JSF/ICEFaces application. I need to pass parameters from one page to another so I user something like:

```
<f:param name="eventName" value="#{item.event_name}" />
```

And then get it in the constructor using:

```
eventName = request.getParameter("eventName");
```

While works fine unless there is a '/' character in the string submitted, it doesn't get parsed properly. I believe I need to escape the '/' parameter with %2F and then parse it back.

Two things:
1- How to do this in ICEFaces or JSF
2- Are there other parameter I have to escape?

Thanks,

Tam

Answer (score 1):

```
<h:outputLink value="http://google.com">click
    <f:param name="eventName" value="#{param.eventName}" />
</h:outputLink>
```

works for me - the browser takes care of url-encoding.

Note that you can get request parameters directly in your page, using `#{param.paramName}`

Comment: hmmmm...it's weird that's exactly what I'm using (h:outputLink) but I'm still getting a '/' in the link!!

Comment: what version of JSF? MyFaces or RI? Facelets or JSP? did you try my example?

Comment: I'm using JSF 1.1 RI, JSP and ICEFaces 1.8.1. I did try your example it didn't work form me

Comment: would it be a problem to switch to jsf 1.2 ?